# iOS Push Notification No Sound

Tags: ios, audio, push-notification

This is the code to register for push

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
{
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

It works fine as the app registers with the server.

The PEM files are also done correctly as I can send a push to my device using sandbox APNS.

When I print my JSON payload from `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I get this:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert = "Test Push Message";
    };
}
```

The issue is when I receive my push (even when the device is set to loud) it doesn't play a sound.

From my knowledge, if you don't specify a sound in the JSON payload it should play the default OS sound.

In my App notification settings on the phone the sound is enabled by default because when I register I specify `UIUserNotificationTypeSound`.

Anyone else come across this issue?

Comment: You should not detect the version like: `if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)` but like rather check if the class is available: `if ([UIUserNotificationSettings class])`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification) you need to specify `default` if you want to the default push notification to be played:

> The name of a sound file in the app bundle. The sound in this file is
> played as an alert. If the sound file doesn’t exist or default is
> specified as the value, the default alert sound is played. The audio
> must be in one of the audio data formats that are compatible with
> system sounds; see Preparing Custom Alert Sounds for details.

The final JSON output:

```
{
    "aps" :     {
        "alert" : "Test Push Message",
        "sound" : "default"
    };
}
```

Comment: yes i got sound and vibrate this way.. but i want only sound. No vibrate.. than how can i do ? thank x in advance...

Comment: The linked documentation is no longer there.

Comment: Used the sound bit of the code with Firebase. Works great

Comment: is this for react-native project or native ios?

Comment: @TM that does not matter. iOS itself ingests the payload delivered from APNS server and processes it.

Comment: Yes, need to specify `"sound" : "default"` in your payload object.

Comment: but how to add this?

Comment: @KhrisVandal how do you sent the push notification? 
You need to a body to APNS message, see the example `JSON` body in my answer.
It depends how you have implemented this, serversider. You can not add a notification sound client side.

Comment: @rckoenes thank you for you answer! Actually Im using fcm-django package to manage push notifications in the server side. I guess I need to modify something in the “send_message()” function to add the apn content… but until now, I didnt figure it out how to do it…

Comment: @KhrisVandal i'm not familiar with the that, better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 15):

You should modify server JSON output to this. `default` it is sound type of the notification on your phone.

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "test",
        "sound": "default"
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i got sound and vibrate this way.. but i want only sound. No vibrate.. than how can i do ? thank x in advance...

Answer (score 3):

for playing sound when our app receives push notification your json must contains sound attribute. so json like this

```
{
    "aps":{
    "alert" :"your test message",
    "sound":"default"
        };
}
```