# How Instagram sends push-notifications to iOS devices without vibration (new likes) and with vibration (replies)?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, vibration

I can't understand how to send push-notifications to my iOS app in two ways:

1. Vibration + Sound
2. No vibration & No sound

Now I can't implement the second one.

Some messengers use the first way to send push-notifications for DMs and the second way for group chats. Instagram notifies you about new likes using the second way as well.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've properly registered for push notifications in the AppDelegate (

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

     return true
}
```

) and stored the device token in `func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)`

It all has to do with the payload you send with the Push Notification. You'll find the Apple documentation on The Remote Notification Payload [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html).

Check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973415/ios-8-1-push-notification-no-sound/*this*) for a pretty good explanation.

But for a quick explanation:

a super basic PN payload would look like this:

```
{
     "aps": {
          "alert": "Slide this alert to open my awesome app"
     }
}
```

1) If you want the works (sound and vibration) you would add the sound key 
and it would look something like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
         "alert" : "Slide this alert to open my awesome app",
         "sound" : "default"
    }
}
```

2) According to the first link I provided, if you want an alert to be silent, you would add the `content-available` key which is really to launch your app in the background but is essentially a silent PN. It would look like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "Slide this alert to open my awesome app",
        "content-available": 1
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.Vibration + Sound

elOso's answer is right. Vibration and sound will not occur together,and only one will occur. The payload looks like

```
{
    "aps" : {
         "alert" : "vibration or Sound",
         "sound" : "default"
    }
}
```

2.No vibration & No sound

elOSo is **wrong**! Simply **remove** the sound key!The payload is

```
{
    "aps" : {
         "alert" : "No vibration & No sound"
    }
}
```